# How to do a PHP POST request for FTX rest API

Tags: php, api, rest, curl, post

I want to change my [account leverage](https://docs.ftx.com/?csharp#change-account-leverage) on FTX with [there rest API](https://docs.ftx.com/?csharp#rest-api). Just for a test because after that I want to post an order. But I cant get both of them working and for some reason I cant figure out how to do it.

So far I am able to do a get request and the authentication for it. This is the code I use for such an get request WITH authentication. I use PHP to do it and use Javascript to fetch the php file.

```php
<?php

// API keys.
$keys = array(
    'apiKey'=> '....',
    'secretKey'=> '....'
);

// Get current time * 1000 to make sure I get a timestamp in milliseconds. Which is needed for the api.
$timestamp = time() * 1000;

// Base url for all api calls.
$baseURL = 'https://ftx.com/api';

// Specified url endpoint. This comes after the baseUrl.
$endPoint = '/account';

// Parameters that are needed for the endPoint its call.
$parameters = '';

// Data that should be added to the encryption of the keys.
$signature = $timestamp . 'GET/api' . $endPoint;

// Hashing the secret key.
$secret = hash_hmac('sha256', $signature, $keys['secretKey']);

// All parts together.
$url = $baseURL . $endPoint . '?' . $parameters;

//Init session for CURL.
$ch = curl_init();

// Options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Make sure curl_exec() will return the result on success and not "success" on success. Also removes error when fetched in Javascript.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

// Init headers for access to the API signed data.
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'FTX-KEY: ' . $keys['apiKey'];
$headers[] = 'FTX-SIGN: ' . $secret;
$headers[] = 'FTX-TS: ' . $timestamp;

// Setting headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// Execute request.
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    echo($error_msg);
}

// Ends the CURL session, frees all resources and deletes the curl (ch).
curl_close($ch);

echo($result);
exit();

?>
```

So again, this worked. But now I want to do a POST request. According to the [authentication documentation](https://docs.ftx.com/?csharp#authentication) I only need to add a request body to the authentication it says. I think these are the $parameters. But im not sure. Anyway, this is my code so far:

```php
<?php

// API keys.
$keys = array(
    'apiKey'=> 'normal',
    'secretKey'=> 'secret'
);

// Get current time * 1000 to make sure I get a timestamp in milliseconds. API asks for it this way.
$timestamp = time() * 1000;

// Base url for all api calls.
$baseURL = 'https://ftx.com/api';

// Specified url endpoint. This comes after the baseUrl.
$endPoint = '/account/leverage';

// Parameters that are needed for the endPoint its call.
$parameters = 'leverage=10';

// Data that should be added to the encryption of the keys. NOTE: Added $parameters.
$signature = $timestamp . 'POST/api' . $endPoint . '?' . $parameters;

// Hashing the secret key.
$secret = hash_hmac('sha256', $signature, $keys['secretKey']);

// For account data
$url = $baseURL . $endPoint . '?' . $parameters;

// Init session for CURL.
$ch = curl_init();

// Options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Make sure curl_exec() will return the result on success and not "success" on success. Also removes error when fetched in Javascript.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

// Tried this, but didn't do much.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);

// Init headers for access to the API signed data.
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headers[] = 'FTX-KEY: ' . $keys['apiKey'];
$headers[] = 'FTX-SIGN: ' . $secret;
$headers[] = 'FTX-TS: ' . $timestamp;

// Setting headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// Execute request.
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo(curl_error($ch));
    exit();
}

// Ends the CURL session, frees all resources and deletes the curl (ch).
curl_close($ch);

echo($result);

?>
```

[This url](https://blog.ftx.com/blog/api-authentication/) is an "example" they give for the authentication. At the bottem there is a "POST signature example" with parameters like this.

```
b'1588591856950POST/api/orders{"market": "BTC-PERP", "side": "buy", "price": 8500, "size": 1, "type": "limit", "reduceOnly": false, "ioc": false, "postOnly": false, "clientId": null}'
```

The first `b'` part I think is something from Python, the long number is the timestamp that I added, the `POST/api/orders` I also have. But the object (I think its a object) I do not have. I tried it but didn't succeed.

The **error** I get from the API is 400 bad request. When I change something with the signature I most of the time get a 401 Unauthorized. For example when changing the timestamp to seconds or removing the '?' in the signature also gives 401.

There can be nothing wrong with the url part, since I did the get request already. So if there is any help, I would appreciate it alot. Before I used Binance, which works perfect. But they are doing some sketchy stuff so I have to move to make sure my money isn't gonna disappear in case they go bad :(

### **EDIT:**

`$parameters = 'leverage=10';` gives me a $signature of

```
1627494427000POST/api/account/leverage?leverage=10
```

and results in a 400 Bad request. API message: "Missing parameter leverage".

`$specialParam = json_encode(['leverage' => '10']);` gives me a signature of

```
1627494427000POST/api/account/leverage?{"leverage":"10"}
```

and results in a 400 Bad request.

Doing the same for both but without the `. '?' .` part in my $signature results for both into a 401 Unauthenticated... API message: "Not logged in"

Comment: You made the request using method `POST` there, but you are still sending the parameter as a GET parameter in the URL, instead of having it JSON encoded in the POST _body_.

Comment: So how should I do it? Do I need this: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);`? I tried it but I am not sure if I gave it the correct data.

Comment: You need to put the parameters into an array, and then encode that array as JSON.

Comment: I believe I have tried that before without success, but I did try alot of crazy things so im not sure. I will try again. Thanks for your help so far. If im at home (currently at work) I will try it out.

Comment: So I changed `$parameters = 'leverage=10';` to `$parameters = json_encode(['leverage' => '10']);` but I have no success :(. I get a 400 bad request

Comment: @Allart were you ever able to solve this? I'm stuck at the exact same spot you were.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Allart!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. It had to do with the `$parameters` and `@signature`. When doing a **POST** request you need to `json_encode()` the parameters and then use it in the `$signature`. See `$specialParam`. Below code makes it possible to chance **leverage**.

```php
<?php

// API keys.
$keys = array(
    'apiKey'=> 'normal',
    'secretKey'=> 'secret'
);

// Get current time * 1000 to make sure I get a timestamp in milliseconds. API asks for it this way.
$timestamp = time() * 1000;

// Base url for all api calls.
$baseURL = 'https://ftx.com/api';

// Specified url endpoint. This comes after the baseUrl.
$endPoint = '/account/leverage';

// Encoded parameters, needed for authentication and post request.
$specialParam = json_encode(['leverage' => 10]);

// Data that should be added to the encryption of the keys.
$signature = $timestamp . 'POST/api' . $endPoint . $specialParam;

// Hashing the secret key.
$secret = hash_hmac('sha256', $signature, $keys['secretKey']);

// For account data
$url = $baseURL . $endPoint;

// Init session for CURL.
$ch = curl_init();

// Options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $specialParam);

// Init headers for access to the FTX API signed data.
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'FTX-KEY: ' . $keys['apiKey'];
$headers[] = 'FTX-SIGN: ' . $secret;
$headers[] = 'FTX-TS: ' . $timestamp;

// Setting headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// Execute request.
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo(curl_error($ch));
    exit();
}

// Ends the CURL session, frees all resources and deletes the curl (ch).
curl_close($ch);

echo($result);
?>
```

Be aware that the error catching part is not really a good/trustable way of catching errors. Atleast for me it didn't always worked out as I hoped it would. I was missing some API messages that say more then 400/401.

Here is another example of how to **set an order** on FTX:

```php
<?php

// API keys.
$keys = array(
    'apiKey'=> 'normal',
    'secretKey'=> 'secret'
);

// Get current time * 1000 to make sure I get a timestamp in milliseconds. API asks for it this way.
$timestamp = time() * 1000;

// Base url for all api calls.
$baseURL = 'https://ftx.com/api';

// Specified url endpoint. This comes after the baseUrl.
$endPoint = '/orders';

$specialParam = json_encode(
    [
        'market'=> 'AAVE/USDT',
        'side' => 'buy',
        'price' => null,
        'type' => 'market',
        'size' => 3
    ]
);

// Data that should be added to the encryption of the keys.
$signature = $timestamp . 'POST/api' . $endPoint . $specialParam;

// Hashing the secret key.
$secret = hash_hmac('sha256', $signature, $keys['secretKey']);

// For account data
$url = $baseURL . $endPoint;

// Init session for CURL.
$ch = curl_init();

// Options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $specialParam);

// Init headers for access to the FTX API signed data.
$headers = array();
// $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'FTX-KEY: ' . $keys['apiKey'];
$headers[] = 'FTX-SIGN: ' . $secret;
$headers[] = 'FTX-TS: ' . $timestamp;

// Setting headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// Execute request.
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo(curl_error($ch));
    exit();
}

// Ends the CURL session, frees all resources and deletes the curl (ch).
curl_close($ch);

echo($result);
?>
```

If your also interrested in a **GET request**, I got you covered. This get the last price there is (not of the past, but of the current).:

```php
<?php
// To make sure I always get the last line existing.
$startTime = time() - 900;

// Base url for all api calls.
$baseURL = 'https://ftx.com/api';

// Specified url endpoint. This comes after the baseUrl.
$endPoint = '/markets/ETH/USDT/candles';

// Parameters that are needed for the endPoint its call.
$parameters = 'resolution=900&start_time=' . $startTime;

// All parts together.
$url = $baseURL . $endPoint . '?' . $parameters;

//Init session for CURL.
$ch = curl_init();

// Options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Make sure curl_exec() will return the result on success and not "success" on success. Also removes error when fetched in Javascript.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

// Execute request.
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    echo($error_msg);
}

// Ends the CURL session, frees all resources and deletes the curl (ch).
curl_close($ch);

echo($result);
?>
```

I hope these are enough examples to make the FTX API usable. Documentation of FTX is unfortunate hard to follow :(

Comment: thanks so much for sharing! Appreciate it!